# Presenting Python enums in PyArrow and Parquet files

Tags: pyarrow

Does PyArrow (Arrow) and its Parquet file format have a native way to serialise Python enums? If not what would be the storage-efficient way to encode enum strings, so that preferably other Parquet readers could also understand them?